# Updating Values Netbeans

Tags: java, sql, database, netbeans, sql-update

I am trying to Update my data from my netbeans to sqlite. there is no problem with the query but when I run the program a message box will appear "java.sql.SQLException:query does not return results". What seems to be the problem?

```
 try{

   String value1=txtId.getText();
   String value2=txtFirst.getText();
   String value3=txtLast.getText();
   String value4=txtUser.getText();
   String value5=txtPass.getText();


   String sql="Update account set id='"+value1+"', fname='"+value2+"', lname='"+value3+"',username='"+value4+"', password='"+value5+"' where id='"+value1+"' ";

   pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);

   rs=pst.executeQuery();
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Data Updated");  
 }

  catch(SQLException e){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int updateCount = pst.executeUpdate();
```

Instead of executeQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Update query:

```
st.executeUpdate("update reservation set busname='"+jTextField10.getText()+"',busno='"+jTextField9.getText()+"',cusname='"+jTextField8.getText()+"',noofpass='"+jTextField7.getText()+"',amount='"+jTextField6.getText()+"' where cusname='"+jTextField8.getText()+"' ");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try:

```
String strQuery = ("update visitor set name='"+jTextField10.getText()+"',bus_no='"+jTextField9.getText()+"',cus_name='"+jTextField8.getText()+"',Date='"+jTextField7.getText()+"',amount='"+jTextField6.getText()+"' where _ID='"+jTextField8.getText()+"' ");
```